# Can you explain to me from where it came equation No.3?

Tags: trigonometry

Equation NO.1
$$ g_k = \hat g \cos(\omega t_k + \varphi)$$

Equation NO.2
$$ g_{k-1} = \hat g \cos(\omega (t_k - \delta t) + \varphi)$$

Can you show me how did we get Equation No. 3?

$$ g_{k-1} =g_k \cos(\omega \delta t)  + \hat g\sin(\omega t_k + \varphi)\sin(\omega \delta t)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition formula for cosine.

$\begin{array}\\
g_{k-1} 
&= \hat g \cos(\omega (t_k - \delta t) + \varphi)\\
&= \hat g \cos(\omega (t_k) + \varphi-\omega (\delta t))\\
&= \hat g \left(\cos(\omega (t_k) + \varphi)\cos(\omega \delta t)+\sin(\omega (t_k) + \varphi)\sin(\omega (\delta t)))\right)\\
&= g_k\cos(\omega \delta t)+\hat g \sin(\omega (t_k) + \varphi)\sin(\omega (\delta t)))\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

$$g_{k-1} = \hat g \cos(\omega (t_k - \delta t) + \varphi) = \hat g \cos(\omega t_k - \omega \delta t + \varphi)$$
Using 
$$\cos(a-b) = \cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b$$
where $a = \omega t_k + \varphi$ and $ b = \omega \delta t$, we get
$$g_{k-1} =  \underbrace{\hat g\cos (\omega t_k + \varphi)}_{g_{k}} \cos \omega \delta t+ \hat g\sin (\omega t_k + \varphi) \sin \omega \delta t$$